# How do I make proper vertical margin between 2 inline blocks?

Tags: css, block, margin, inline, display

I have two divs with display:inline block next to each other, however the 2nd one's width can change to be so long that it will fall under the first div. That is fine, but the problem is that there is no vertical space between the 2 divs when this happens. I can solve this by adding margin-bottom to the first div, but then this causes the 2nd div to be a bit lower even when it is sitting to the right of the first div.

Comment: Could you please post your HTML and CSS code?

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using?  As you can see below, two `inline-block` divs retain a margin when one slips below the other.  (In fact, getting rid of the margin between `inline-block` elements is a bit tricky, but that's another question.)

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
}
#top {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
#right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="top"></div><div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is "vertical-align:top;".